# Python: How can I create a list of character with "_" as a default value?

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list whose size is equal to "word_len" and the default char is "_" which can be replaced later by the correct guess of the user. How can I do it?
My current code:-

```
import random

word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
word_len = len(chosen_word)

guess_letter = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

final_list = []

for character in chosen_word:
    if character == guess_letter:
        print("Right")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

Comment: If you keep track of remaining letters in a dictionary `remaining = dict.fromkeys(chosen_word,"_")` you can remove guessed letters as you go with (`remaining.pop(guess_letter,"")` and print the result so far with `print(*(remaining.get(c,c) for c in chosen_word))`.  When `remaining` is empty, the word has been found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a display time concern.  You don't need to store the displayed words with their `_`, you can simply generate them at display time.

To do so, you have to keep track of the letters that were `guessed`.  Then you can check against each character of each word in `word_list`.

```
guessed = "abcd"
word_list = [ "cat", "dog", "cab" ]

print( [ ''.join([ l if l in guessed else '_' for l in word]) for word in word_list ] )
```

```
['ca_', 'd__', 'cab']
```

If the nested list comprehensions are making your eyes go crosseyed at first, here's an equivalent long form:

```
display_words = []
for word in word_list:
    new_word = ""
    for l in word:
        if l in guessed:
            new_word = new_word + l
        else :
            new_word = new_word + '_'
    display_words.append(new_word)

print(display_words)
```